# What is a cardinal basis spline?

Tags: terminology, special-functions, signal-processing, interpolation

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline#Cardinal_B-spline):

> the normalized **cardinal B-splines** tend to the Gaussian function

and writes them as "**B**<sub>*k*</sub>".  Meanwhile, [cnx.org Signal Reconstruction](http://cnx.org/content/m10788/latest/) says:

> The **basis splines** ***B***<sub>n</sub> are shown ... as the order increases, the functions approach the Gaussian function, which is exactly ***B***<sub>∞</sub>.

[image: basis splines]

but then says

> as the order increases, the **cardinal basis splines** approximate the sinc function, which is exactly ***η***<sub>∞</sub>.

[image: cardinal basis splines]

Likewise, [Signal Reconstruction with Cardinal Splines](http://cnx.org/content/m11126/latest/#sec2) uses similar notation of ***η***<sup>n</sup> for "cardinal spline".

So which is it?  Does a "cardinal basis spline" approximate a Gaussian or a sinc?  "B-spline" and "basis spline" are the same thing, right?  Is there any relationship to [this cardinal spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline#Cardinal_spline)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roughly speaking ...

If you fix certain quantities (degree, knots, orders of continuity) then the set of all splines forms a vector space, which, of course, has several different bases.

Two common bases are the cardinal splines, and the b-splines.

It's true that "b-spline" is an abbreviation of "basis spline", but the vector space of splines has other bases, besides the b-splines. Confusing, I guess.

I wasn't aware of the limits as degree goes to infinity, but the statements sound plausible. Assuming you use the right knot sequences, I can see how the b-spline basis functions might tend to the Gaussian function, and the cardinal basis functions might tend to the sinc function.

Comment: Ok, so "cardinal B-spline" and "cardinal basis spline" are not the same thing?

Comment: The word "cardinal" is used in two different senses (unfortunately). I just discovered that some people use the term "cardinal b-spline" to refer to a b-spline whose knots are successive integers.

Cardinal basis splines are the things I mentioned in my answer -- they are the splines shown in your second set of pictures.

So, not the same thing.